# Resharper - Move to Resource not working in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, resharper

Using Resharper 8.2, Razor in MVC 5

In Razor files, when text appears as raw text,

```
<br>
    Localize Me
```

There is no way to localized it with Resharper's F6 (Move to Resource)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper has not supported it yet http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-276872.

It supports localization like so:

```
<p>
    @String.Format("Localize Me")
</p>
```